# Rotate text in XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I am generating the xsl-fo document for my XML content and then passing this content to one of the third party DLL that will generate the PDF. I have a requirement to display a test in 45 degrees angle. How to achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't in pure XSL-FO - the rotations available to the orientation properties are in 90 degree increments. Try embedding an SVG image instead.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer. It isn't possible in xsl-fo. You'll have to use images (jpg, gif, svg) instead.

Comment: Are there other properties apart from http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#glyph-orientation-horizontal and http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#glyph-orientation-vertical which specify rotation?

Comment: @RobertG you can search through the document for 'rotat' and you'll find a few discussions, but all properties are set to increments of 90 degrees.

Comment: With Apache FOP as a rendering library, reference-orientation works for my 90-degrees-rotation scenario, but not really that well. <table-cell ...><block-container reference-orientation="90"><block...>...</block></block-container></table-cell>

Answer (score 1):

AH Formatter has an `axf:transform` extension property that can do multiple sorts of transformations, including rotating a block by a specified angle.